# Django: How to associate a user with a request factory

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing, django-tests

I am writing some tests for a form on a Django site.  I want to test that a logged in user is able to use the form assuming correct input.  To that end, I am using a Django request factory.  I can't seem to get my test user logged in though.  That, or I'm not even making the request correctly.  I'm not sure.  Relevant code below:

```
def create_user():
        username = 'User '+id_generator()
        return User.objects.create(username = username, password = 'password')

def test_can_register_deck(self):
        t = create_empty_tourney()
        u = create_user()
        d = create_deck(u)
        rf = RequestFactory()
        request = rf.post(reverse('tourney:tourney', args=(t.slug,)),{'deck' : d})
        request.user = u
        response = self.client.get(reverse('tourney:tourney', args=(t.slug,)), request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The request has to think the user is logged in, or the rest of the test won't work.  This throws no errors, but I'm not even sure my `response` is utilizing the request correctly.  Am I correctly telling the test to "make a post request to the tourney page as this user, and try to submit a deck"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `RequestFactory` and the client are two different ways of testing django views.

The `request` that is returned from `rf.post` is meant to be passed directly to a view function. If you were to do that, i think you will find that, the user will be detected as logged in.

I looked at the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py), and the documentation, and I don't see where the test client accepts a request.  You can log in a user with the test client using:

```
self.client.login(
   username=u.username,
   password='password')
```

Comment: I understand now.  Thanks for the direction.  For those interested, my `response` line needed to be this: `response = tourney(request, t.slug)` where `t.slug` is a required positional argument.